# Why does the inner circle fill the outer circle?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, xml-drawable

I'm trying to make a small dark circle within a large light circle using xml in Android. Both circles have a color, a size and a stroke. Why does the small dark circle fill the 50 dp instead of being 28dp?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--big light circle-->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />

            <size
                android:width="50dp"
                android:height="50dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#404040" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--small dark circle-->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#AEAEAE" />

            <size
                android:width="28dp"
                android:height="28dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#464646" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The usage of the drawable:

```
   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonPositive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_choice_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"/>
```

The xml generates [image: Wrong xml] But I want it to generate [image]
(the outer circles are the same size, this screenshot doesn't show it correctly)

Comment: on which version of android are you testing it?

Comment: The screenshot is of what it shows on the Design tab of the xml file in Android Studio. It renders API 23. I've tried running it on a 4.3, 5.0 and 6.0 device and it all shows the same.

Comment: strange.. try applying padding on the <item level (e.g. android:left)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with applying padding on the item level.
It doesn't autocomplete for me when I do '<item paddi' and not either when i do <item> <padd

Comment: use `android:left` etc to apply padding `<item  android:left="10dp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--big light circle-->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />

        <size
            android:width="50dp"
            android:height="50dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#404040" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!--small dark circle-->
<item android:bottom="11dp"
    android:left="11dp"
    android:right="11dp"
    android:top="11dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#AEAEAE" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#464646" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: This worked for me! It shouldn't be 22dp though, as you do it on both sides it is 11dp. I suggest you add the </layer-list> tag.

Comment: Can you explain why the <size> tag didn't work as I had expected?

Comment: Not sure of the reason why. I faced the same problem and only the above solution worked.