# android Layerlist with solid fill circle inside transparent fill outer circle

Tags: android

How can i create an android layerlist drawable which gives me something like this

[image]

I have managed to generate just the outer circle only with the below code.But can seem to find a way to add the solid one inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#1582AF"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: may be help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672404/why-does-the-inner-circle-fill-the-outer-circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layer list is look like below:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item> <!--Your outer blue border shape-->
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <size
                android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#1582AF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--Your inner blue Solid circle shape-->
    <item android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#1582AF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Size does not work in shape tag and stretches the shape!